# Marginal medians of the Dirichlet distribution

Tags: median, beta-distribution, marginal-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

I am working with a 3 dimensional Dirichlet distribution with parameters $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3>0$. I have been trying to figure out a useful 'median' concept for this distribution. The vector of marginal medians has been suggested elsewhere, as each marginal distribution is a Beta distribution and their medians can be found relatively easily. However, the sum of these medians does not add up to 1, so it has to be scaled.

I have observed that if you divide the simplex from each vertex to the opposite side, splitting the mass in halves, that these three lines do in fact intersect at a common point, and this is precisely the scaled marginal median point as found above. I have been thinking about how I would prove such a claim. Perhaps if we define a continuous mapping of density from a uniform Dirichlet to my distribution, that the centroid of the uniform distribution would move to this 'marginal median' point. Or is there some other geometric proof that pops into mind?